# UimageView in UITabbleViewCell the frame not right

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I try to set imageView cornerRadius ,but the frame not right until tap cell or scroll
(0.0, 0.0, 158.0, 413.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 158.0, 413.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 158.0, 413.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 96.0, 120.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 96.0, 120.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 96.0, 120.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 96.0, 120.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 96.0, 120.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 96.0, 120.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 96.0, 120.0)
I use auto layout

[before tap cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMr15.png)

[after tap cell frame update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BICVb.png)

I already put the code in

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    leftImageView.layer.cornerRadius = leftImageView.layer.frame.width / 2
    leftImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    leftImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    leftImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is the `leftImageView.layer.frame.width` didn't have the correct width at that time. Check the frame in licecycles.

Comment: i knew , but seem the ui is correct ,frame not update ,already check the frame at viewdidappear still same  (0.0, 0.0, 158.0, 413.0)  not correct

Comment: add some delay for example 0.1 second before code for corner radius

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
       super.layoutSubviews()

       if leftImageView.layer.cornerRadius != leftImageView.layer.frame.width / 2     
       {

           leftImageView.layer.cornerRadius = leftImageView.layer.frame.width / 2
           leftImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
           leftImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
           leftImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
           
           setNeedsLayout()
           layoutIfNeeded()
       }
    }
```